# Mongoose - $and not functioning properly, need to find array with both items

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've got a chat based application that I'm working on.  A private message between two individuals is a Chat model, which looks like this:

```
let schema = new Schema({
  members: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: models.user.name }],
  chatHistory: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: models.message.name }]
})
```

For the chat route, I have it so when you send a message to an individual, it's supposed to look in the Chats, find and return the chat if both the req.params.id (the Id of the person you're contacting) and the req.session.uid (your Id) are present in the members array.  Unfortunately, it's finding and returning the first chat that has either the req.params.id or the req.session.uid, so essentially the $and in Mongo is functioning as an or instead. Here's the route that is causing problems:

```
createChat: {
    path: '/profile/:id/chat',
    reqType: 'post',
    method(req, res, next) {
        let action = 'Create new chat'
        Chats.findOne({ $and: [{ members: { $in: [req.session.uid] }, members: { $in: [req.params.id] } }] }).populate('members chatHistory')
            .then(chat => {
                if (!chat) {
                    Chats.create({ members: req.session.uid })
                        .then(newChat => {
                            newChat.members.push(req.params.id);
                            newChat.save()
                                .then(chat => {
                                    Chats.findById(chat._id).populate('members')
                                        .then(chat => {
                                            res.send(handleResponse(action, chat))
                                        })
                                })
                        })
                } else {
                    res.send(handleResponse(action, chat))
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return next(handleResponse(action, null, error))
            })
    }
}
```

I know that the piece that's causing problems is the following:

```
Chats.findOne({ $and: [{ members: { $in: [req.session.uid] }, members: { $in: [req.params.id] } }] }).populate('members chatHistory')
```

Does anyone know the fix to get the and to actually behave as such instead of an or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`members` key is duplicated in `$and` - which is not a valid object. it should be,

```
//atleast on match
Chats.findOne({ $and: [{ members: { $in: [req.session.uid, req.params.id] } }] }).populate('members chatHistory')
```

or

```
//for both match
Chats.findOne({ $and: [{ members: { $in: [req.session.uid] }},{ members: { $in: [req.params.id] }}] }).populate('members chatHistory')
```

Comment: I switched that, but now it only returns to me the same chat every time.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/
Based on this, I believe when you put them in one array like { members: { $in: [req.session.uid, req.params.id] } that it returns a match to EITHER of those parameters instead of both.

Comment: That appears to have worked! I'll need to bug test it a bit but I think that works. Thank you!